# conexion a base de datos

Tags: java, base-de-datos

tengo una duda

Cuales son las diferentes formas de conectar una aplicacion java ee a base de datos?

he visto que se puede por medio de pool de conexiones e hibernate pero cuales son las otras formas y cual es la mejor para poderla usar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues hay varias maneras, una de ellas es efectivamente *Hibernate*, pero éste es solo uno de los frameworks o plugins existentes para hacer la conexión con base de datos. Por otro lado también se puede hacer una conexión a la base de datos directamente y sin el uso de ningún framework usando la clase *DataSource*, acá la documentación.

Todos los frameworks requieren de un ***JDBC*** (el controlador de la base de datos) para poder manejar la conexión a base de datos. Este controlador cambia dependiendo de cada proveedor (eso quiere decir que, por ejemplo Oracle tiene su propio ***JDBC*** llamado *OJDBC*, *Postgresql* tiene uno propio también y así sucesivamente).

Personalmente recomiendo *Hibernate* por su robustez y fácil configuración, pero si lo que necesitas es algo más ligero que solo consulte a la base de datos, *MyBatis* está bien. No intentes hacer la conexión sin ningún Framework a menos que tus motivos sean de aprendizaje, ya que puede llegar a ser muy engorroso.

- **Acá tienes un tutorial de Hibernate y Maven:**

> https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/maven-3-hibernate-3-6-oracle-11g-example-xml-mapping/

- **Acá uno de MyBatis y Spring:**

> https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/mybatis-3-spring-integration-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

El acceso a base de datos se realiza por medio de JDBC (Java Data Base connectivity).

JDBC es una especificación (API) provista por Oracle (como JAVA) e implementada por cada Base de Datos Específica... tienes las Clases e Interfaces Java de API en el JRE (Java Runtime Environment) y tienes que tener un JAR adicional con la implemntación, ej: Oracle DB, Postgres, MySQL, etc.. cada BD tiene su propio JAR.

Hibernate, es una forma de acceder a los datos pero funciona sobre JDBC... es un motor ORM (como Mapeo Relación-Objeto) que ayuda a construir de manera 'Rapida' una aplicación donde uno pueda persistir los Objetos..

Pool de Conexiones tambien trabaja sobre JDBC y es una Biblioteca Utilitaria que te ayuda a adminstrar las conexiones de Base de Datos.. Abrir, Cerrar, Tener un limite de conexiones disponibles, liberar si alguien tiene ocupada una conexión por mucho tiempo etc.

En Conclusión, Basicamente JDBC es la única forma oficial de acceso a Bases de Datos.